# javascript - custom object prototype method turns into index in array loop

Tags: javascript

Here's something weird. I have defined a custom prototype method for `object` called `getSize`:

```
if (!Object.prototype.getSize) {
    Object.prototype.getSize = function() {
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
        }
        return size;
    };
}
```

It gives you the size of an object. Pretty simple so far, right?
Here's where I get confused:

```
var l = ["foo", "bar"]
for (var i in l) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

results are:

```
0
1
getSize
```

**Why is `getSize` there???**

*edit*
I know that arrays in javascript are objects too. My question is why is the method turned into an index, instead of remaining a method. It doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `getSize` is an enumerable property, you could define it to be non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getSize', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function() {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
  }
});
```

But you could also do:

```
Object.keys(object).length;
```

Comment: I didn't know methods have an `enumerable` definition. This is very cool, thanks for the answer! I'll use `defineProperty` from now on

Comment: btw, `Object.keys(l)` returns `['0', '1']` [even if I don't](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/qwcctogs/) set `enumerable: false` - how come?

Comment: @yuvi because `Object.keys` doesn't use the prototype chain. All of this stuff is well documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: @DaggNabbit thanks. MDN is well documented, but that doesn't mean you always know where to look or what this and that means. Obviously, `Object.keys` doesn't go through the same process as `for...in`, because then you would get the same results. I'm wondering what that process *is* though (or does that happen on a very low level of code?)

Answer (score 3):

Because `["foo", "bar"]` is an Object in JavaScript too. Try to run `typeof ["foo", "bar"]` in console. It will return `"object"` to you. So you have extended Arrays methods too. Once you have done this you will need to check for `hasOwnProperty` in all `for..in` iterations as well.

This happens to all [global objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) in JavaScript

Comment: I know that arrays are objects too. But why doesn't it inherit the method, why is it turned into an index? That makes no sense

Comment: elclanrs answer to this. You can read more about enumerables at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties